# How find coordinates of index?

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I have a matrix `A` logical and I have an other matrix `Idx` which represent index of certain points of `A`. I would like to find coordinates of these index. How can I do ?

```
A=[false    false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   true
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   false   false   true    false   false   false
false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false
false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false
false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false
false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false
false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false
false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false
false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false
true    true    false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false]
idx = [5 20 63 96 153]
```

Comment: try [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)

Comment: It gives me NAN :-/

Comment: Can you provide a (small) example matrix for `A` and `Idx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ind2sub:

```
A=[false    false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   true;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   false   true    false   false   false;
    false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false;
    false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false;
    false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false;
    false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false;
    true    true    false   false   false   false   false   false;
    false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false];
idx = [5 20 63 96 153];
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(A),idx)
```

which gives:

```
x =

 [1     1     3     5     8]

y =

 [5    20    21    12     6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using

```
idx = find(A);
```

Instead of this use

```
[row col] = find(A);
```

Comment: no I don't use find this why I needed an other solution ;-)

Comment: Yep with user2999345's solution

Comment: great, I'm glad about that